# Python Numpy According a 2-D array's value to assign values to a 3-D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say, an array `A` which shape is `(2,3)` and values are in `0, 1, 2, 3`

Another array `B` which shape is `(2, 3, 4)`

Goal:According to `A` position and value to add `1` in `B`. **without** using loop. maybe numpy.where? is possible?

Example:

`A = [[0, 1, 3],[2, 1, 0]]`

`B = np.zeros((2, 3, 4))`

*something I'm looking for help*

```
B = [[[1, 0, 0, 0]
      [0, 1, 0, 0]
      [0, 0, 0, 1]]

     [[0, 0, 1, 0]
      [0, 1, 0, 0]
      [1, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

further more, if value in `A` is `Nah`, what will happen. can we just do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

**Check out this code:**

**Method-1**

```
B[0,[0,1,2], A[0]] = 1
B[1,[0,1,2], A[1]] = 1
```

---

**Method-2**

```
import numpy as np

A = [[0, 1, 3],[2, 1, 0]]

B = np.zeros((2, 3, 4))

for i,j in zip(range(len(A)),A):
    for k,l in zip(range(len(j)),j):
        B[i][k][l] = 1

print(B)
```

Comment: Goal:According to A position and value to add 1 in B. __without using loop__.

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I hope not to use for loop.  can numpy.where solves this ? or some others.

Comment: @PennYan @Jan Wait within few minute I am adding `with numpy` also

Answer (score 0):

I've got an idea.

one hot coding.

```
numpy.eye(4)[A]
```

so that `A` has the same shape as `B`.

```
A + B
```